# sizeof(*this) in class definition

Tags: c++

Can we do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() { std::cout << sizeof(*this) << '\n'; }
};
```

In C Standard i see the following:

**ISO/IEC 9899:2011**

> 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> 8 ... The type is incomplete until immediately after the } that
>   terminates the list, and complete thereafter.

But in C++ Standard i can't find any analogue.

The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has incomplete type, so can we write such code or not?

Comment: +1 for researching the specification before posting.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can write such code because the compiler has to treat it as though the class definition is complete inside class method implementations.

For example it has to treat it as though you wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo();
};

// Methods declared in the body of a class are implicitly inline
// Inline, however, probably doesn't mean what you think it means:
inline Foo::Foo() { std::cout << sizeof(*this) << '\n'; }
```

Comment: No this is not allowed." invalid use of `this' at top level" error.it is not inside any member function.'this' come into existence when class is instantiated. but in this code we are using it before its existence.

Comment: @Arpit: the initialization in the liveworkspace.org example is permitted by C++11 because of 9.2/2: "Within the class member-speciﬁcation, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, exception-speciﬁcations, and **brace-or-equal-initializers** for non-static data members" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 8):

Inside the member function body, the class is complete- else, you could not access any other member functions, nor access any member variables, which would make a fairly worthless member.

Comment: Can we also write something like this? liveworkspace.org/code/hN4ty$0

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov no, but this however does work: [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/pPdNc$0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write and also the result will also be correct.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo
{
public:
       int x;
   Foo() { std::cout << sizeof(*this) << '\n'; }
};
int main(){
    Foo b;
    b.x=5;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```